# libuv combines mutliple async calls and invokes callback once

Tags: c, multithreading, event-loop, libuv

**Requirement** : A UDP server that on receiving an UDP packet and stores the received packet to one of the two queues. A worker thread is associated with each queue, and the associated thread picks up packet from the front of the queue, processes it and writes it into a in-memory cache system.

**Constraints** : solution has to be based on event-loop(libuv) and written in C

**My Solution**

- register a call-back for incoming UDP which adds the received packet to one of the two queues and raises a uv_async_send
- two global uv_sync_t objects are created one for each queue and used as parameter for uv_async_send. For ex : if packet is added to queue-one then uv_sync_t object-1 is used as parameter for uv_async_send. Similarly, if packet is added to queue-two then uv_sync_t object-2 is used
- two threads are started, each having their own loop and a handle bound with a callback

  - In thread-one uv_sync_t object-1 is bound against a function (say funcA).
    In thread-two uv_sync_t object-2 is bound against another function (say funcB)
  - funcA and funcB reads "SINGLE" packet from corresponding queue and stores it in the in-memory cache

**The problem**
The Client sends large number of packets which registers large number of events in the server. Now the problem is that libuv combines multiple calls into one and invokes a single callback(which removes a SINGLE node from queue). This leads to situation where nodes are being added to the queue at a faster rate and removed at a very slow rate. Can these rates be balanced ?

Is there a better way to design the server using event-looping library libuv ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are queueing the packets in one thread but processing in another, it's possible that they work at slightly different rates. I'd use a thread-safe queue (have a look at concurrencykit.org) and process the entire queue on the async callback, instead of just processing a single packet.